# This question is not a duplicate; the answers don't answer this question

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[This question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/44075/which-episode-is-the-splitting-point-between-the-original-fma-anime-and-brotherh?rq=1) is not a duplicate of [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/55/whats-the-difference-between-the-fma-and-fma-brotherhood-series).  [An answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/58/13647) (importantly, not the accepted answer) on the second question comes close to answering, but does not do so.  The first question should be re-opened.

The two are similar and related, but not duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

The question has been rectified to reflect the proper duplicate question.